# How to return a List inside this bounded generic method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I have class Response

```
public class Response<T extends ResponseData> {
    private final T data;
    //other fields, getters, setters ...
}
```

and the empty interface ResponseData:

```
public interface ResponseData {
}
```

It takes any object as data but this object must implement the "empty" interface which I created just to force all classes returned inside "data" element be of same super type

Now the problem is that I need to return a `List` inside the data element, but:

1. I don't find it clean to create a `ResponseData` implementation which serves only as a wrapper around my `List`
2. I can't return the `List` directly because it doesn't belong to my code and therefore I can't make it implement the marker interface (`ResponseData`)

So is there a solution to my problem other than the one that says I should delete the marker interface and allow any object to be returned in the data element?

**n.b.** : My purpose of the marker interface is to make any created classes which will be returned inside the data element inside the response,for anyone who reads them, clear towards their purpose of existence

**n.b.** : As mentioned in number 1 above, I know that this solution exists:

```
class ResponseDataWrapper implements ResponseData{
    private final List<SomeType> responseList;
    
    //getters,setters
}
```

but it is not clean as in this case there is a layer of nesting (i.e. the wrapper class) which is not necessary between the `List` and the "data" element in the response

Answer (score 0):

Have a response object like this that Returns the list:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class SomeCoolResponseForAnApi implements ResponseData{
    private List<SomeObject> theListYouWantToReturn;

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @Data
    public static class SomeObject{
        private String name;
        private String age;
    }
}
```

PS: I have used lombok, you can just use regular getters and setters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not help, look at number 1 above, I know this solution exists but it is not clean as the real data (list) in the response is now nested inside an object which in turn is inside the data element, I want to get rid of this object somehow

Comment: I understand that you have a marker interface to explicitly make it clear that class that implements it is a response  object. 

So my answer actually suffices your point. I believe this is the only way.